# How to draw sprite on a sprite so that both of them will be seen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have two sprites one of them is a tank sprite the other is a protection sprite. I want to draw the protection sprite on the tank sprite. The images of the sprites are as follows:

[image]

[image]

When I draw the protection sprite on the tank sprite, the result is the following: [image]

Center of the protection sprite is empty (according to photoshop, I checked multiple times). I am using the following code for the protection sprite

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join(imgFolderExp, "Powerups", "protection-3.png")).convert(), (40, 48))
self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
```

What should I do in order to draw only the lines of the protection sprite so that in the middle of the combined draw, the tank will be seen?

Comment: Why do you set a color key when you use a PNG? PNGs have per pixel alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) have per pixel alpha. It is not necessary to set a color key. Simply `blit` the protector on the tank. [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) changes the pixel format to a format without alpha per pixel and removes the transparency information. Use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead:

```py
filepath = os.path.join(imgFolderExp, "Powerups", "protection-3.png") 

protector_surf = pygame.image.load(filepath).convert_alpha()

self.image = pygame.transform.scale(protector_surf, (40, 48))
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!